# as3 hitTestObject class object hitting class

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to load multiple bubbles and have them bounce around the screen. If they hit each other they should "do something from my code".

Here is the code that is not working:

```
if(e.target.hitTestObject(e.target.getChildAt(1)))
            {
                trace("Items hit");// Runs on every enter frame. Should not. 
            }
```

Here is my Main timeline: numberPop.as

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    import flash.system.Capabilities;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.system.Capabilities;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

    // Greensock Annimation
    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;
    import com.greensock.plugins.*;
    import com.greensock.plugins.TransformAroundCenterPlugin;
    TweenPlugin.activate([TransformAroundCenterPlugin]);
    TweenPlugin.activate([TransformAroundPointPlugin]);
    import com.greensock.plugins.CacheAsBitmapPlugin;

    import com.theBubble;


    public class numberPop extends MovieClip 
    {

        public var numberBubble:theBubble;

        ///screen rez
        public static var _screenX:int;
        public static var _screenY:int;

        public var Desktop:Boolean;
        public var iPhone:Boolean;

        public var i:Number = 2;

        public var Jesus:Array = new Array('3','4');

        public function numberPop() 
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            setStage(null);

            //addBubble(3);
            TweenMax.delayedCall(1, addBubble);
            TweenMax.delayedCall(3, addBubble);

        }


        public function addBubble()
        {

            numberBubble = new theBubble(i,this);
            addChild(numberBubble);
            numberBubble.name = ""+i+"";
            trace("I here " + numberBubble.name);
            i++;
        }

        public function setStage(e:Event)
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            if (flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX > stage.fullScreenWidth)
            {

                _screenX = stage.fullScreenWidth;
                _screenY = stage.fullScreenHeight;
                //Rez = "Screen Height";
                trace("Second: " + _screenY);

            }
            else
            {
                if(iPhone)
                {
                _screenX = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
                _screenY = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
                }
                else
                {
                _screenX = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
                _screenY = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
                }

                trace("Second: " + _screenY);
            }

            // _screenX = stage.stageWidth;
            //_screenY = stage.stageHeight;
        }


        //////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////
    }

}
```

Here is my loaded class

```
package com {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    import flash.system.Capabilities;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.system.Capabilities;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;


    // Greensock Annimation
    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;
    import com.greensock.plugins.*;
    import com.greensock.plugins.TransformAroundCenterPlugin;
    TweenPlugin.activate([TransformAroundCenterPlugin]);
    TweenPlugin.activate([TransformAroundPointPlugin]);
    import com.greensock.plugins.CacheAsBitmapPlugin;


    public class theBubble extends MovieClip 
    {

        public var num:Number;


        public var _screenX:Number;
        public var _screenY:Number;

        public var xDie:Boolean = true;
        public var yDie:Boolean = true;

        public var Main:MovieClip;


        public function theBubble(num:Number,mc:MovieClip) 
        {
            super();
            this.num = num;
            trace("Number is: " + num);

            Main = mc;


            this.Number_text.text = "" + num + "";

            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bubbleAction);
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkHit);


            trace(Main);

        }




        public function checkHit(e:Event)
        {

            if(e.target.hitTestObject(e.target.getChildAt(1)))
            {
                trace("Items hit");
            }



            var xVal = 5;
            var yVal = 5;

            if(xDie)
            {
            this.x = this.x + xVal;
            }
            else
            {
                this.x = this.x - xVal;
            }

            if(this.x >= numberPop._screenX - this.width)
            {
                xDie = false;
            }
            if(this.x <= 0)
            {
                xDie = true;
            }
            ///////
            if(yDie)
            {
                this.y = this.y + yVal;
            }
            else
            {
                this.y = this.y - yVal;
            }
            if(this.y >= numberPop._screenY - this.height)
            {
                yDie = false;
            }
            if(this.y <= 0)
            {
                yDie = true;
            }




        }



        public function bubbleAction(e:Event)
        {

            trace(this.name);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `if(e.target.hitTestObject(e.target.getChildAt(1)))` - so the `e.target` is a Bubble and `e.target.getChildAt(1)` is a child of that bubble, so it will always hit, no?

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.getChildAt(1)` is a child of e.target, so it will always hit. You're going to want to somehow separate Bubble and whatever you're testing.

Comment: A bit late, I know, but a class like Manager should do (using composition*)